# Throwback in dates without Weekends

Tags: mysql

I often use this `query1` to go back 6 days on a variable date:

```
query1 = SELECT
    DATE_FORMAT((DATE('2018-11-21') - INTERVAL(S.`I` - 1) DAY), '%Y-%m-%d')
    AS VAR
    FROM `HELPER_SEQ`
    AS S WHERE S.`I` <= 6;
```

With the help of this auxiliary table with a sequence inserted there.

```
CREATE TABLE `HELPER_SEQ` (`I` tinyint(3) UNSIGNED NOT NULL);
INSERT INTO `HELPER_SEQ` (`I`) VALUES (1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6);
```

Question:

How can I avoid output weekends days using query1?
In a such way that the output go back in 6 useful days, in this example starting on '2018-11-21' the output would be ->

```
| 2018-11-21 | 
| 2018-11-20 |
| 2018-11-19 | 
| 2018-11-16 | 
| 2018-11-15 | 
| 2018-11-14 |
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can utilize [`DayName()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_dayname) function to get the name of the weekday corresponding to a Date. We will utilize this function's result to restrict weekends by `NOT IN ('Saturday', 'Sunday')`.

Also, we will need to increase the number generator range **upto 10**. Because there is a possibility that we can come across 2 weekends (total 4 days) on either side of 5 weekdays.

So, we need 2 (first pair of weekend days) + 5 (weekdays) + 2 (second pair of weekend days) + 1 (6th weekday) = 10 dates to consider. An example of this edge case would be when an input date is Sunday.

We will need to use `LIMIT 6` to restrict the result upto 6 days only, in the non-edge cases.

**Schema (MySQL v5.7)**

```
CREATE TABLE `HELPER_SEQ` (`I` tinyint(3) UNSIGNED NOT NULL);
INSERT INTO `HELPER_SEQ` (`I`) VALUES 
(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9),(10);
```

**Query**

```
SELECT
    DATE_FORMAT((DATE('2018-11-21') - INTERVAL(S.`I` - 1) DAY), '%Y-%m-%d')
    AS VAR
FROM `HELPER_SEQ` AS S 
WHERE S.`I` <= 10 
  AND DAYNAME(DATE_FORMAT((DATE('2018-11-21') - INTERVAL(S.`I` - 1) DAY), '%Y-%m-%d')) NOT IN ('SATURDAY', 'SUNDAY')
ORDER BY VAR DESC
LIMIT 6;
```

**Result**

```
| VAR        |
| ---------- |
| 2018-11-21 |
| 2018-11-20 |
| 2018-11-19 |
| 2018-11-16 |
| 2018-11-15 |
| 2018-11-14 |
```

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/4k3iGoRnuRnKKsoDu5mfMU/1)

---

**Edge Case Demo - Input date: 25 Nov 2018 (Sunday)**

```
CREATE TABLE `HELPER_SEQ` (`I` tinyint(3) UNSIGNED NOT NULL);
INSERT INTO `HELPER_SEQ` (`I`) VALUES 
(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9),(10);
```

**Query #2**

```
SELECT
    DATE_FORMAT((DATE('2018-11-25') - INTERVAL(S.`I` - 1) DAY), '%Y-%m-%d')
    AS VAR
FROM `HELPER_SEQ` AS S 
WHERE S.`I` <= 10 
  AND DAYNAME(DATE_FORMAT((DATE('2018-11-25') - INTERVAL(S.`I` - 1) DAY), '%Y-%m-%d')) NOT IN ('SATURDAY', 'SUNDAY')
ORDER BY VAR DESC
LIMIT 6;
```

**Result**

```
| VAR        |
| ---------- |
| 2018-11-23 |
| 2018-11-22 |
| 2018-11-21 |
| 2018-11-20 |
| 2018-11-19 |
| 2018-11-16 |
```

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/4k3iGoRnuRnKKsoDu5mfMU/4)

Comment: Madhur Bhaiya, But my idea is that it would continue for six days.
In this case starting on 2018-11-21 the intended output would be: 
| 2018-11-21 | 2018-11-20 | 2018-11-19 | 2018-11-16 | 2018-11-15 | 2018-11- 14 |;

How is this possible ?

Comment: @NelsonBustier please specify this in the question. I will update answer accordingly.

Comment: @NelsonBustier you will need 6 days only ? not more than that ?

Comment: Madhur Bhaiya, Yes, just only 6 days. Please .

Comment: @NelsonBustier recommended to use the updated answer now. Do check (it handles edge cases).