# MySQL. How to get the difference between two dates excluding weekends?

Tags: mysql, sql

```
date1 = 2017-01-26 10:59:17
date2 = 2017-01-27 11:34:55
```

How to get the difference between them while excluding weekends?
In this example, 28.01 and 29.01 is the weekends.

Accordingly, as it is necessary to exclude these 48 hours of a difference..
Thanks in advance!

PS
While I get the difference so:

```
TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, date1, date2)

| tid  | sec_to_time(diff)| date1               | date2              | 
| 5861 | 97:23:25         | 2017-01-26 10:59:17 | 2017-01-30 12:22:42|
```

Comment: Are you asking this question with regards to an actual SQL table, or just as an abstract calculation as you have shown above?

Comment: i'm guessing your date ranges could be decades apart?

Comment: You want difference in seconds? Could you explain the purpose of this calculation?

Comment: I added a sample table to the question @Joakim Danielson

Comment: @ignn check this answer to get some ideas: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53418090/2469308 You will need to use a number/sequence generator table and join with it to get the differences as per your requirements, with some maths.